# Change color based on percentage value of other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have in Excel format the following columns: `cost`, `Sales Margin` and `Margin`.

What I would like to do:

- If `Sales Margin` is more than 15% then Margin Column color should GREEN,  OR
- If `Sales Margin` is less than 15% then Margin Column color should YELLOW, OR
- If `Sales Margin` is less than 10% then Margin Column color should RED.

Can someone please help me to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If `Sales Margin` is in ColumnB then first format as much of ColumnB with red (standard formatting) as required.Then select ColumnB and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=C1>=0.1
```

and yellow. Then repeat with this formula:

```
=C1>0.15
```

and green.